# What could cause interrupts from MCP23017 suddenly stop working?

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

I have 4 rotary encoders connected to an MCP23017 which in turn is connected to interrupt port 0 on the arduino (and to I2C of course). Everything works fine: I get interrupts for all 4 rotary encoders, can read the values for them and even store these values in the EEPROM and load them in setup.

[image: Fritzing schematic of the (initially) working setup]

Now, I connect a WS2812 LED to the arduino (with a resistor and a capacitator in front of it). I connect the UNO and the led lights up. I attach the serial console (resetting the UNO) and it stops working (LED does not light up). This could just be simple wiring mistake and is not my real problem.

I remove the LED (and the capacitor) from the board and start everything up again. I can see via the serial console that the UNO works, however it does not receive any interrupts anymore. I exchange the MCP23017 thinking I fried it somehow but that doesn't change anything either...

Is there some sort of state the UNO has I could have affected?

Or could I have fried the interrupt "sub-system" on the UNO (again: all the other stuff still works)?

EDIT: The code is here: https://github.com/qollin/Liting/blob/master/src/Liting.cpp

Comment: You need to set the CONFIGURATION REGISTER (ADDR 0x05) to control how INTA and INTB react.

Comment: I wonder if the LED is a red herring and you just have some iffy code that is being picky about when it works. Could you post your code?

Comment: Just added a link to the main file (it uses quite a lot of libraries, though)...

Comment: I think I figured out whats wrong: you need to reset the interrupt handling of the MCP in setup() (by reading from both INT pins). Otherwise the MCP may start in a state where it does not generate new interrupts, because it waits for the old ones to be handled...

Comment: @qollin please post your solution as an answer so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out whats wrong: you need to reset the interrupt handling of the MCP in setup() (by reading from both INT pins). Otherwise the MCP may start in a state where it does not generate new interrupts, because it waits for the old ones to be handled...

Comment: I'd just tie nRESET of the MCP' to the nRESET of the Arduino, but your call.